# Usage of Navigator pattern

Tags: design-patterns

The scenario is that we are writing an application to let people to fill online form to get insurance. The form is so large so that I have divided into many sections. My manager ask me to use navigator pattern to control the flow of the navigation (section 1 to section 5 or you get the idea). I have not heard of Navigator pattern. Does my manager just made it up or I am missing anything here?

Comment: if you can be specific to technology we can be of more help. Plain HTML + JS will be your easiest bet if its web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is talking about wizard-like steps.